# WD MBWE II (White Strip Light) 2TB - unable to access data

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-0

I have a WD MBWE II (White Strip Light) 2TB - (WD20000H2NC-00)

Was working fine until a few days ago. I guess there was a power failure and after that I am unable to access the 'Public' or the 'Download' folder anymore.

I have been searching for answers everywhere but came up empty handed.

Web GUI still works, SSH works. I hooked up both the drives on my PC and UFS Explorer sees the drive. But so far I am unable to retrieve any of my data. I do not remember what RAID setting I used when I first got the drive. I can see from GUI that it is set as "Stripe".

The drive contains 10 years of family pictures which I really do not want to loose. Sadly and stupidly, I didn't even keep a backup of this drive.

Can somebody please help or point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance for your help.

Disk Utility on Ubuntu reports 1405 bad sectors on one drive.

How can I retrieve my data? Please help.

Logs below:

```
~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md[012345678]

/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 15 08:36:17 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1959872 (1914.26 MiB 2006.91 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1959872 (1914.26 MiB 2006.91 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Nov  1 13:53:29 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 04f7a661:98983b3b:26b29e4f:9b646adb
         Events : 0.266

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 15 08:36:18 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 256896 (250.92 MiB 263.06 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 256896 (250.92 MiB 263.06 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Oct 30 22:08:21 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : aaa7b859:c475312d:efc5a766:6526b867
         Events : 0.10

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sat Sep 25 10:01:26 2010
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 1947045760 (1856.85 GiB 1993.77 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Nov  1 13:30:53 2013
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : 01dae60a:6831077b:77f74530:8680c183
         Events : 0.97

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       1       8       20        1      active sync   /dev/sdb4
/dev/md3:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 15 08:36:18 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 987904 (964.91 MiB 1011.61 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 987904 (964.91 MiB 1011.61 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Nov  1 13:26:33 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 3f4099f2:72e6171b:5ba962fd:48464a62
         Events : 0.54

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
mdadm: md device /dev/md4 does not appear to be active.
mdadm: md device /dev/md5 does not appear to be active.
mdadm: md device /dev/md6 does not appear to be active.
mdadm: md device /dev/md7 does not appear to be active.
mdadm: md device /dev/md8 does not appear to be active.

~ # cat /etc/mtab

securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
/dev/md2 /DataVolume xfs rw,usrquota 0 0
/dev/md4 /ExtendVolume xfs rw,usrquota 0 0

~ # df -k

Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               1929044    145092   1685960   8% /
/dev/md3                972344    123452    799500  13% /var
/dev/ram0                63412        20     63392   0% /mnt/ram

~ # mdadm -D /dev/md2

/dev/md2:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sat Sep 25 10:01:26 2010
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 1947045760 (1856.85 GiB 1993.77 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Nov  1 13:30:53 2013
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : 01dae60a:6831077b:77f74530:8680c183
         Events : 0.97

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       1       8       20        1      active sync   /dev/sdb4


~ # mdadm -D /dev/md4

mdadm: md device /dev/md4 does not appear to be active.

~ # mount

/dev/root on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw)
/dev/pts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
/dev/md3 on /var type ext3 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/ram0 on /mnt/ram type tmpfs (rw)

~ # cat /var/log/messages

Oct 29 18:04:50 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 29 18:04:59 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 29 18:04:59 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 29 18:17:45 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 29 18:17:53 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 29 18:17:53 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 00:50:11 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 00:50:19 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 00:50:19 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 16:29:47 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 16:30:00 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 16:30:00 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 18:27:22 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 18:27:30 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 18:27:30 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 19:06:03 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 19:06:10 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 19:06:10 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3462]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 19:14:58 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3462]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Oct 30 19:20:05 shmotashNAS daemon.alert wixEvent[3462]: Thermal Alarm - System temperature exceeded threshold.(66 degrees)
Oct 30 19:58:29 shmotashNAS daemon.alert wixEvent[3462]: HDD SMART - HDD 1 SMART Health Status: Failed.
Oct 30 22:05:39 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 13043, console /dev/null: '/usr/bin/killall'
Oct 30 22:05:39 shmotashNAS syslog.info System log daemon exiting.
Oct 30 22:08:09 shmotashNAS syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.1.1
Oct 30 22:08:09 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 22:08:19 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 22:08:25 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 22:08:37 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 22:08:44 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 22:08:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler:   +++++++++++++++ START OF ./miocrawler at 2013:10:30 - 22:08:46 [Version 01.09.00.96] ++++++++++++++  
Oct 30 22:08:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_db_init ... 
Oct 30 22:08:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: ****** database does not exist. ret = -1, creating path 
Oct 30 22:08:49 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_db_init ...Done. 
Oct 30 22:08:50 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mcUtilsInit() Creating free queue pool  
Oct 30 22:08:51 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mcUtilsInit() Done.  
Oct 30 22:08:51 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === inotify init done.  
Oct 30 22:08:51 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_trans_updater_init() ... 
Oct 30 22:08:52 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_trans_updater_init() ...Done. 
Oct 30 22:08:52 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === Walking directory done.  
Oct 30 22:08:57 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 22:08:57 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 22:08:57 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 22:08:57 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 22:09:10 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4605, console /dev/null: '/bin/touch'
Oct 30 22:09:10 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4607, console /dev/ttyS0: '/sbin/getty'
Oct 30 22:09:10 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: System Startup - System startup.
Oct 30 22:09:16 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Oct 30 22:14:14 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 22:14:21 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 22:14:21 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3557]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 22:29:36 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3557]: System Reboot - System will reboot.
Oct 30 22:29:40 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 5974, console /dev/null: '/usr/bin/killall'
Oct 30 22:29:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info System log daemon exiting.
Oct 30 22:47:56 shmotashNAS syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.1.1
Oct 30 22:47:56 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3461]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is down.
Oct 30 22:48:02 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3461]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 22:48:02 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3461]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 22:48:09 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler:   +++++++++++++++ START OF ./miocrawler at 2013:10:30 - 22:48:09 [Version 01.09.00.96] ++++++++++++++  
Oct 30 22:48:09 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_db_init ... 
Oct 30 22:48:09 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: ++++++++ database exists: ret = 0 
Oct 30 22:48:10 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_db_init ...Done. 
Oct 30 22:48:10 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mcUtilsInit() Creating free queue pool  
Oct 30 22:48:11 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mcUtilsInit() Done.  
Oct 30 22:48:11 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === inotify init done.  
Oct 30 22:48:11 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_trans_updater_init() ... 
Oct 30 22:48:11 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_trans_updater_init() ...Done. 
Oct 30 22:48:11 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === Walking directory done.  
Oct 30 22:48:27 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4079, console /dev/null: '/bin/touch'
Oct 30 22:48:27 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4080, console /dev/ttyS0: '/sbin/getty'
Oct 30 22:48:28 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3461]: System Startup - System startup.
Oct 30 22:49:01 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3461]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Oct 30 23:51:11 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3461]: System Reboot - System will reboot.
Oct 30 23:51:16 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 6498, console /dev/null: '/usr/bin/killall'
Oct 30 23:51:16 shmotashNAS syslog.info System log daemon exiting.
Oct 30 23:54:19 shmotashNAS syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.1.1
Oct 30 23:55:37 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3476]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 30 23:55:37 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3476]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 30 23:55:44 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler:   +++++++++++++++ START OF ./miocrawler at 2013:10:30 - 23:55:44 [Version 01.09.00.96] ++++++++++++++  
Oct 30 23:55:44 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_db_init ... 
Oct 30 23:55:44 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: ++++++++ database exists: ret = 0 
Oct 30 23:55:45 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_db_init ...Done. 
Oct 30 23:55:45 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mcUtilsInit() Creating free queue pool  
Oct 30 23:55:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mcUtilsInit() Done.  
Oct 30 23:55:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === inotify init done.  
Oct 30 23:55:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_trans_updater_init() ... 
Oct 30 23:55:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_trans_updater_init() ...Done. 
Oct 30 23:55:46 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === Walking directory done.  
Oct 30 23:55:58 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4115, console /dev/null: '/bin/touch'
Oct 30 23:55:58 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4116, console /dev/ttyS0: '/sbin/getty'
Oct 30 23:55:58 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3476]: System Startup - System startup.
Oct 30 23:56:33 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3476]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Oct 31 00:29:14 shmotashNAS auth.info sshd[5409]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 31 00:31:25 shmotashNAS auth.info sshd[5486]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.100 port 50785 ssh2
Oct 31 00:33:44 shmotashNAS auth.info sshd[5565]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.100 port 50817 ssh2
Oct 31 00:36:39 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 5680, console /dev/null: '/usr/bin/killall'
Oct 31 00:36:39 shmotashNAS syslog.info System log daemon exiting.
Oct 31 00:40:44 shmotashNAS syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.1.1
Oct 31 00:40:51 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3464]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Oct 31 00:40:51 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3464]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Oct 31 00:41:00 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler:   +++++++++++++++ START OF ./miocrawler at 2013:10:31 - 00:41:00 [Version 01.09.00.96] ++++++++++++++  
Oct 31 00:41:00 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_db_init ... 
Oct 31 00:41:00 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: ++++++++ database exists: ret = 0 
Oct 31 00:41:00 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_db_init ...Done. 
Oct 31 00:41:01 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mcUtilsInit() Creating free queue pool  
Oct 31 00:41:02 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mcUtilsInit() Done.  
Oct 31 00:41:02 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === inotify init done.  
Oct 31 00:41:02 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_trans_updater_init() ... 
Oct 31 00:41:02 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_trans_updater_init() ...Done. 
Oct 31 00:41:02 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === Walking directory done.  
Oct 31 00:41:14 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4101, console /dev/null: '/bin/touch'
Oct 31 00:41:14 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4102, console /dev/ttyS0: '/sbin/getty'
Oct 31 00:41:15 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3464]: System Startup - System startup.
Oct 31 00:41:47 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3464]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Oct 31 01:13:19 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 5385, console /dev/null: '/usr/bin/killall'
Oct 31 01:13:19 shmotashNAS syslog.info System log daemon exiting.
Nov  1 13:26:25 shmotashNAS syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.1.1
Nov  1 13:26:32 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3471]: Network Link - NIC 1 link is up 100 Mbps full duplex.
Nov  1 13:26:32 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3471]: Network IP Address - NIC 1 use static IP address 192.168.1.102
Nov  1 13:26:38 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler:   +++++++++++++++ START OF ./miocrawler at 2013:11:01 - 13:26:38 [Version 01.09.00.96] ++++++++++++++  
Nov  1 13:26:38 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_db_init ... 
Nov  1 13:26:38 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: ++++++++ database exists: ret = 0 
Nov  1 13:26:39 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_db_init ...Done. 
Nov  1 13:26:39 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mcUtilsInit() Creating free queue pool  
Nov  1 13:26:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mcUtilsInit() Done.  
Nov  1 13:26:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === inotify init done.  
Nov  1 13:26:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: mc_trans_updater_init() ... 
Nov  1 13:26:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === mc_trans_updater_init() ...Done. 
Nov  1 13:26:40 shmotashNAS syslog.info miocrawler: === Walking directory done.  
Nov  1 13:26:52 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4078, console /dev/null: '/bin/touch'
Nov  1 13:26:52 shmotashNAS daemon.info init: Starting pid 4079, console /dev/ttyS0: '/sbin/getty'
Nov  1 13:26:52 shmotashNAS daemon.info wixEvent[3471]: System Startup - System startup.
Nov  1 13:27:28 shmotashNAS daemon.warn wixEvent[3471]: Media Server - Media Server cannot find the path to one or more of the default folders: /Public/Shared Music, /Public/Shared Pictures or /Public/Shared Videos. Please verify that these folders have not been removed or that the names have not been changed.
Nov  1 13:44:48 shmotashNAS auth.info sshd[5375]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.103 port 50217 ssh2
Nov  1 13:51:08 shmotashNAS auth.info sshd[5894]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.103 port 50380 ssh2
```

Comment: If ssh works, can you ssh into it and explore filesystem using local shell? Maybe you can still recognize something of importance.

Answer (score 0):

go to the western digital site. They have software that is for recovering lost blocks of data. If that doesn't work then Google "Data Recovery". There will be plenty of options to try. Though I would stick with known manufacturers rather than freeware or such.

Comment: I have the WD Data Lifeguard software but I am afraid to use it. I do not want to loose my data. Is it safe to use the WDL software on a HDD which is part of a RAID0 setup?

Comment: That software is only for testing the drives. The name is deceptive lol. I went to the WD support site they have decided to outsource the data recovery. I did a little searching for you and found this site, http://www.raid-recovery-guide.com/raid-basics.aspx it is all about raid recovery and has recovery software comparisons as well.

Comment: You need to figure out what RAID level you used. The Stripe setting can be RAID level 0 or RAID level 5. Now the good news and the bad news. Raid 0 Striped doesn't use redundancy. So if one drive completely fails the data is lost forever. Although it may be possible to get some small files from other drives in the array. Refer to the site I linked under section RAID Levels. Now good news. If it is RAID Level 5 Striped set with Parity then you should be able to use your RAID software to rebuild the lost information.